# Create subsystem using Simulink: PWM output signal with current input signal

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment, pwm, simulink-library

I don't have too much experience with MATLAB/Simulink, so I have a current signal in Simulink that I want to convert to a PWM signal, and I don't actually know the right way to do it. First thought is to create a subsytem to implement a frame model to convert to input current to PWM.
I would appreciate any help about this subject.

Comment: What will be the realation between current signal and PWM? If you can give more detail, I'd like to help you.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not actually sure about the relation between the values that's why I popped up the question here. What should be normally taken into consideration in this case?

Comment: I do not know,  a direct relationship between a current value and a PWM wave. Current is actually means flow of electrons  and PWM means Pulse Width Modulation. Generally PWM signals have frequency and duty cycle. I think you need to understand and specifiy much more detailed way for anyone to be able to help you.